# C# + FPS в 2д играх

Tags: c#

Собрался писать игру - на всеми любимом c#, но возникли кое какие трудности, с выбором средств реализации.
Игра 2д.
Ну скажем кое-что общее имеет `Worms`.
Самое главное и основное требование к ней - это офк ультра стабильный фпс.
И я вот бьюсь над выбором:

1: `unity`
2: `Xna/monogane`

Что из этого лучше всего для 2Д?

Comment: Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. И такие вопросы закрываются, соответственно.

Comment: В целом, как-то же работают десятки тысяч игр на Unity и других движках? Соответственно все эти загоны - не нужны. Надо брать то, что ближе и интересней - и делать

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вообще то проблемы с FPS связаны либо с недостаточной мощностью ПК игрока, либо с плохой оптимизацией. Движок не особо влияет на этот параметр. А про костыли в Unity, это скорее костыли разрабов-новичков в своих скриптах, ибо сам такого не замечал.

Answer (score 0):

Выбор конечно останется за тобой, но если не писал на unity, monogame будет проще для начала с fps все хорошо стабильно работает.